# Create a string from an objects properties using Lamba Expressions

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

This is related to my question at [Fun (?) with Linq Expressions in extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936579/fun-with-linq-expressions-in-extension-methods) but this is more of an abstraction of a piece I'm trying to understand.  I'm really having difficulty wrapping my brain around this concept.

Given an object defined as such:

```
public class item
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
}
```

and an `IEnumerable<item> foo`,

let's say I want to write an extension method such that the expression

```
foo.GetFullDescription(x => x.itemId.ToString() + "(" + x.itemName + ")")
```

would equal an `IEnumerable<string>` containing the concatenated items as defined in the Lambda expression.  For example, if my `foo` object contained exactly one `item` object like so:

```
{
fooItem.itemId = 1
fooItem.itemName = "foo"
fooItem.itemDescription = "fooDescription"
}
```

... and I assigned a variable to the result of the extension method like so:

```
var bar = foo.GetFullDescription(x => x.itemId.ToString() + "(" + x.itemName + ")");
```

... I would get `bar` to be an `IEnumerable<string>` with one item in it, and that item would equal `1(foo)`.

How would I write that extension method?  The first part is relatively straightforward:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFullDescription(this IEnumerable<item> target, <some expression?> expr){


}
```

Some help would be appreciated.  Simple explanations would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example from LINQPad.  Just copy and past it in.

```
void Main()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(GetFullDescription(new Item(){itemId = 2, itemName="two"}, 
    x => x.itemId.ToString() + "(" + x.itemName + ")"));
}

public delegate string Lambda (Item item);

public class Item
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static string GetFullDescription(Item item, Lambda lambda){
    return lambda(item);
}
```

You just have to declare a Delegate that returns a string, is called whatever you like, and accepts a single Item parameter.  Remember a Delegate is basically a function variable, were you define your function's input and output.  Here I think is your full extension method

```
public delegate string Lambda (Item item);
public static string GetFullDescription(this IEnumerable<Item> items, Lambda lambda){
    foreach(var item in items){
         return yield lambda(item); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... this looks to be in the right direction of what I'm looking for, but rather tied to the `Item` class.  I'll see if I can get this working with generics.

Comment: I was able to use this in a generic manner.  Fantastic, and a lot simpler than I thought it would be.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description (if I'm reading it correctly), it looks like you just need to use Select.

```
var itemsAsStrings = foo.Select(x => x.itemId.ToString() + "(" + x.itemName + ")");
```

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish this task, what I'm really looking for is an education on how to do it using a Linq Expression so that I could apply the idea more generically.