# How do I force MVC4/Razor to render a tag inside a SelectListItem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, font-awesome

I can have tags inside option tags, and it works (don't know if it's valid HTML4/5, but it works in Firefox at least):

```
<select>
  <option><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add item</option>
  <option><i class="icon-remove"></i>Remove item</option>
  <option><i class="icon-edit"></i>Edit item</option>
</select>
```

I'm placing Bootstrap/FontAwesome webfont icons in those option tags.

But I'm using MVC4/Razor, and I can't get the correct syntax to make it render properly. It encodes all those inner tags and I get `&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc.

This is what I'm doing:

```
// first I make a new list with the icons inside
var items = Model.Items.Select(q => new SelectListItem() {
  Selected = q.Selected,
  Text = "<i class=\"icon-add\"></i>" + q.Text,
  Value = q.Value
  });
// then render the dropdown
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, items, "All")
```

How do I get this working?

Comment: did you check to make sure that Model.Items has data? and plz include your error msg in your post.

Comment: Looks like [option only allows text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html), so what I want works, but isn't valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've *selected* an easy easy *option*...

Simply put the FontAwesome classes on the `<option>` tag instead of a nested child `<i>` tag. That way the markup is valid.

Of course this needs to be done manually in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this out of the box. Depending how often you need to use it - I personally would recommend doing it manually via a loop.

If you want, you could write an extension method/helper for the drop down list.

I found a similar example here, though this guy uses it to custom the 'select' tag, you'll want to custom the 'options' tag: [Fun (?) with Linq Expressions in extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936579/fun-with-linq-expressions-in-extension-methods/7938038#7938038)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I thought as much. I think the `@Html` extension methods do the encoding themselves, and so there's no way to get them to emit raw markup. I guess a custom extension method is the only *option for me to select...*